# Retrofit calls onError block when response received in JsonObject

Tags: android, retrofit2

I need to send a `JsonArray` to service, and receive `JsonObject` in return.

I used following code.

```
 @POST
    Call<JsonArray> networkUtilityJsonArrayPostCall(

            @Url String url,
            @Body JsonArray jsonArray);
```

Then i called it by using following code.

```
 callJsonArray = api.networkUtilityJsonArrayPostCall(URL, jsonArray)
```

It receives response code `200`, but does not execute `onResponse` block, as it expects `JsonArray` in response.

```
   callJsonArray.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
@POST
Call<JSONObject> networkUtilityJsonArrayPostCall(
        @Url String url,
        @Body JsonArray jsonArray);
```

instead of the method below

```
@POST
Call<JsonArray> networkUtilityJsonArrayPostCall(
        @Url String url,
        @Body JsonArray jsonArray);
```

and replace respective inherited methods

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
@POST
Call<ResponseBody> networkUtilityJsonArrayPostCall(
        @Url String url,
        @Body JsonArray jsonArray);
```

Now body parameter in your callback holds the server response and you can parse it by calling `responseBody.string();`

Answer (score 1):

Call for `ResponseBody` instead of `JsonArray` : If you are not sure about the `JSON structure`.

```
@POST
Call<ResponseBody> networkUtilityJsonArrayPostCall(@Url String url, @Body JsonArray jsonArray);
```